# React - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

even after binding delta in the constructor.

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count : 1
        };

        this.delta.bind(this);
    }

    delta() {
        this.setState({
            count : this.state.count++
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.delta}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: in ES6, use can you use arrow function for function declaration to fix this issue.

Comment: ^ this should be the correct answer

Comment: I changed my response function into ES6, and hurrey, its working.

Answer (score 601, accepted):

This is due to `this.delta` not being bound to `this`.

In order to bind set `this.delta = this.delta.bind(this)` in the constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        count : 1
    };

    this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);
}
```

Currently, you are calling bind. But bind returns a bound function. You need to set the function to its bound value.

Comment: What on earth is the point of ES6 classes if their methods don't have proper lexical `this` binding, and then don't even expose a syntax for binding their context directly on their definition!?

Comment: i understand your point but if i write code in componentWillMount() then how will i bind

Comment: @sureshpareek Once you bind your function in the constructor, it should then be bound when you call it from any lifecycle hook.

Comment: Yes forgot about this one. Haha

Comment: Personally, I fixed the problem directly in the JSX like this: `<button onClick={()=>this.delta}>+</button>` (via anonymous function)

Comment: @AgmLauncher I don't think it's an issue with ES6 classes themselves, instead it's an issue with the way React components work.

Comment: @AgmLauncher use of Lambda functions implicitly bind this. If you defined `delta` as `delta = () => { return this.setState({ count: this.state.count++ }); };` the code would also work. Explained here: 
https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4

Answer (score 185):

In **ES7+** (ES2016) you can use the experimental [function bind syntax](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-function-bind) operator `::` to bind. It is a syntactic sugar and will do the same as Davin Tryon's answer.

You can then rewrite `this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);` to **`this.delta = ::this.delta;`**

---

For **ES6+** (ES2015) you can also use the ES6+ [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`=>`) to be able to use `this`.

```
delta = () => {
    this.setState({
        count : this.state.count + 1
    });
}
```

Why ? From the Mozilla doc :

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own *this* value [...]. This proved to be annoying with an object-oriented style of programming.
>
> Arrow functions capture the *this* value of the enclosing context [...]

Comment: Nice article describing this in detail: http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/

Comment: What is the advantage of using one over the other, besides the syntax?

Comment: The bind syntax is cleaner because you can keep the normal scope of your method.

Comment: The bind syntax is not part of ES2016 or ES2017.

Comment: @FelixKling ya I don't know why this is upvoted. It didn't work for me but the "long hand" way using .bind() did work.

Comment: It is (was ?) an experimental syntax for ES7 in 2015 https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/05/14/function-bind

Comment: @stackoverflow should add the ability to add a bounty to any answer.

Comment: This is much more like a "normal" OO language like Java/C#.  You should not have to explicitly bind "this" to methods within a class.

Answer (score 36):

There is a difference of context between ES5 and ES6 class. So, there will be a little difference between the implementations as well.

Here is the ES5 version:

```js
var Counter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() { return { count : 1 }; },
    delta: function() {
        this.setState({
            count : this.state.count++
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
              <button onClick={this.delta}>+</button>
            </div>
            );
    }
});
```

and here is the ES6 version:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { count : 1 };
    }

    delta() {
        this.setState({
            count : this.state.count++
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
              <button onClick={this.delta.bind(this)}>+</button>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

Just be careful, beside the syntax difference in the class implementation, there is a difference in the event handler binding.

In the ES5 version, it's

```
              <button onClick={this.delta}>+</button>
```

In the ES6 version, it's:

```
              <button onClick={this.delta.bind(this)}>+</button>
```

Comment: Using arrow functions or binding in JSX is a bad practice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36677733/why-shouldnt-jsx-props-use-arrow-functions-or-bind.

Answer (score 33):

You dont have to bind anything, Just use Arrow functions like this:

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count: 1
        };

    }
    //ARROW FUNCTION
    delta = () => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count++
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.delta}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: that works what's the difference please why is that?

Comment: The this scope with arrow functions is inherited from the context.

With regular functions, this always refers to the nearest function, while with arrow functions this problem is removed, and you won't need to write var that = this ever again. @RezzagRidha

Comment: As of 2019 this is the way to go (Y)

Comment: This should be the top answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

When using ES6 code in React always use arrow functions, because the **this** context is automatically binded with it

**Use this:**

```
(videos) => {
    this.setState({ videos: videos });
    console.log(this.state.videos);
};
```

**instead of:**

```
function(videos) {
    this.setState({ videos: videos });
    console.log(this.state.videos);
};
```

Comment: If using the arrow function and the **parameter variable** is the same as the **key variable**, I would recommend using it as 
`this.setState({videos});`

Comment: This is what did it for me.  I'm new to node, and the docs for the axios module was incompatible with react and setState

Answer (score 9):

if your are using ES5 syntax then you need to bind it properly

```
this.delta = this.delta.bind(this)
```

and if you are using ES6 and above you can use arrow function, then you don't need to use **bind()** it

```
delta = () => {
    // do something
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to bind your methods with 'this' (default object).
So whatever your function may be just bind that in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked:false };

    this.handleChecked = this.handleChecked.bind(this);
}

handleChecked(){
    this.setState({
        checked: !(this.state.checked)
    })
}

render(){
    var msg;

    if(this.state.checked){
        msg = 'checked'
    }
    else{
        msg = 'not checked'
    }

    return (
        <div>               
            <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked = {this.state.checked} onChange = {this.handleChecked} />
            <h3>This is {msg}</h3>
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use:

```
<button onClick={()=>this.delta()}>+</button>
```

Or:

```
<button onClick={event=>this.delta(event)}>+</button>
```

If you are passing some params..

Comment: It is bad practice to use arrow functions in JSX

Answer (score 7):

you have to bind new event with **this** keyword as i mention below...

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count : 1
        };

        this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);
    }

    delta() {
        this.setState({
            count : this.state.count++
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.delta}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

There are two solutions of this issue:

The first solution is add a constructor to your component and bind your function like bellow:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        ...

        this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);
    }
```

So do this:

```
this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);
```

Instead of this:

```
this.delta.bind(this);
```

The second solution is to use an arrow function instead:

```
delta = () => {
       this.setState({
           count : this.state.count++
      });
   }
```

Actually arrow function **DOES NOT** bind it’s own `this`. Arrow Functions lexically `bind` their context so `this` actually refers to the **originating context**.

For more information about bind function:

[Bind function](https://javascript.info/bind)
[Understanding JavaScript Bind ()](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/)

For more information about arrow function:

[Javascript ES6 — Arrow Functions and Lexical `this`](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4)

Answer (score 6):

You need to bind this to the constructor and remember that changes to constructor needs restarting the server. Or else, you will end with the same error.

Comment: Was pulling my hair out because i didn't restart the server.

Answer (score 6):

This error can be resolved by various methods-

- If you are using **ES5** syntax, then as per [React js Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) you 
  have to use **bind** method.

  Something like this for the above example:

  `this.delta = this.delta.bind(this)`
- If you are using **ES6** syntax,then you need not use **bind** method,you can 
  do it with something like this:

  `delta=()=>{
      this.setState({
          count : this.state.count++
      });
  }`

Answer (score 4):

Arrow function could have make your life more easier to avoid binding **this** keyword. Like so:

```
 delta = () => {
       this.setState({
           count : this.state.count++
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.14.8/dist/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@0.14.8/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">

        class App extends React.Component{

            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                    counter : 0,
                    isToggle: false
                }
            this.onEventHandler = this.onEventHandler.bind(this);   
            }

            increment = ()=>{
                this.setState({counter:this.state.counter + 1});
            }

            decrement= ()=>{
                if(this.state.counter > 0 ){
                this.setState({counter:this.state.counter - 1});    
                }else{
                this.setState({counter:0});             
                }
            }
            // Either do it as onEventHandler = () => {} with binding with this  // object. 
            onEventHandler(){
                this.setState({isToggle:!this.state.isToggle})
                alert('Hello');
            }


            render(){
                return(
                    <div>
                        <button onClick={this.increment}> Increment </button>
                        <button onClick={this.decrement}> Decrement </button>
                        {this.state.counter}
                        <button onClick={this.onEventHandler}> {this.state.isToggle ? 'Hi':'Ajay'} </button>

                    </div>
                    )
            }
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
        document.getElementById('root'),
      );
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your bind statement from what you have to 
=> 
   **this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);**

Answer (score 2):

Adding

> onClick={this.delta.bind(this)}

will solve the problem .
this error comes when we try to call the function of ES6 class ,
So we need to bind the method.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking for the same sulution when using axios, or any fetch or get, and using setState will return this error.

What you need to do, is to define the component outside, as so:

```
componentDidMount(){
  let currentComponent = this;
  axios.post(url, Qs.stringify(data))
     .then(function (response) {
          let data = response.data;
          currentComponent.setState({
             notifications : data.notifications
      })
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

though this question had a solution already, I just want to share mine to make it be cleared, hope it could help:

```
/* 
 * The root cause is method doesn't in the App's context 
 * so that it can't access other attributes of "this".
 * Below are few ways to define App's method property
 */
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
     this.sayHi = 'hello';
     // create method inside constructor, context = this
     this.method = ()=> {  console.log(this.sayHi) };

     // bind method1 in constructor into context 'this'
     this.method1 = this.method.bind(this)
  }

  // method1 was defined here
  method1() {
      console.log(this.sayHi);
  }

  // create method property by arrow function. I recommend this.
  method2 = () => {
      console.log(this.sayHi);
  }
   render() {
   //....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. **Check state** 
            check state whether you create particular property or not

```js
this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: ""
            }
            
           
            
this.setState(() => ({ 
             comments: comments          //comments not available in state
             }))
```

2.**Check the (this)** 
             if you doing setState inside any function (i.e handleChange) check whether the function bind to this  or the function should be arrow function .

**## 3 ways for binding this to the below function##**

```js
//3 ways for binding this to the below function

handleNameChange(e) {  
     this.setState(() => ({ name }))
    }
    
// 1.Bind while callling function
      onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)}
      
      
//2.make it as arrow function
     handleNameChange((e)=> {  
     this.setState(() => ({ name }))
     })
    
//3.Bind in constuctor 

constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            email: ""
        }
        this.handleNameChange = this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If using inside axios , Use the Arrow(=>) in then

axios.get('abc.com').then((response) => {});

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions

one:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            count : 1
        };

        this.delta = this.delta.bind(this);
    }
```

two:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.delta()}>+</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```