# React Redux - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

New to this.

I have looked for answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33988671/react-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined?noredirect=1&lq=1).

am using Redux as well. As per good practice I have a container "AddressContainer" and its component "Address".

The AddressContainer is as follows -

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
        import { connect } from 'react-redux'
        import { Field, change } from 'redux-form'
        import { Col, Panel, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
        import Select from 'react-select'

        import Address from './address'

        import { ensureStateData, getSuburbs } from './actions'

        import { CLIENT_FORM_NAME } from '../clients/client/client'

        export class AddressContainer extends Component {
          static contextTypes = {
            _reduxForm: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
          }

          constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context)

            this.state = {
              selectedSuburb: null,
            }
          }

          componentDidMount() {
            this.props.ensureStateData()
          }

          // Manage asyncSelect for new data request - for suburbs.
          handleSuburbSearch = (query) => {
            const { addressData } = this.props
            const companyStateId = addressData.companyStateId

            if (!query || query.trim().length < 2) {

              return Promise.resolve({ options: [] })
            }
            const queryString = {
              query: query,
              companyStateId: companyStateId,
            }
            return getSuburbs(queryString)
              .then(data => {
                return { options: data }
              })
          }


          render() {
            const {
              initialValues,
              addressData,
              updatePostcodeValue,
            } = this.props


            //const { value } = this.state
            const sectionPrefix = this.context._reduxForm.sectionPrefix


            if (addressData.isLoading || !addressData.states.length) {
              return (
                <p>Loading</p>
              )
            }
            if (addressData.error) {
              return (
                <p>Error loading data</p>
              )
            }


            const companyStateId = addressData.companyStateId
            //  initialValues = {
            //    ...initialValues.Address=null,
            //    state: addressData.states.find(option => option.stateId === companyStateId),
            //  }


            return (
              <Address 
                initialValues={initialValues}
                addressData={addressData}
                handleSuburbSearch={this.handleSuburbSearch}
              />
            )
          }
        }
        const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
          initialValues: state.address,
          companyStateId: state.companyStateId,
          addressData: state.addressData,
        })

        const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
          ensureStateData: () => dispatch(ensureStateData()),
          getSuburbs: (values) => dispatch(getSuburbs(values)),
          updatePostcodeValue: (postcode, sectionPrefix) => dispatch(change(CLIENT_FORM_NAME, `${sectionPrefix ? (sectionPrefix + '.') : ''}postcode`, postcode))
        })

        export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AddressContainer)
```

The Address component is as follows -

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
      import { connect } from 'react-redux'
      import { Field, reduxForm, change } from 'redux-form'
      import { Col, Panel, Row } from 'react-bootstrap'
      import Select from 'react-select'
      import FormField from '../formComponents/formField'
      import TextField from '../formComponents/textField'
      import StaticText from '../formComponents/staticText'

      export const ADDRESS_FORM_NAME = "Address"

      export const Address = (props) => {
        const { addressData, handleSuburbSearch } = props
        const { reset } = props

        return (
          <Panel header={<h3>Client - Address Details</h3>}>
            <Row>

              <Field component={TextField}
                name="address1"
                id="address1"
                type="text"
                label="Address Line 1"
                placeholder="Enter street 1st line..."
                fieldCols={6}
                labelCols={3}
                controlCols={9}
              />
              <Field component={TextField}
                name="address2"
                id="address2"
                type="text"
                label="Address Line 2"
                placeholder="Enter street 2nd line..."
                fieldCols={6}
                labelCols={3}
                controlCols={9}
              />
            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Field
                component={props => {
                  const { input, id, placeholder, type } = props
                  const { fieldCols, labelCols, controlCols, label, inputClass } = props
                  // just the props we want the inner Select textbox to have
                  const { name, onChange } = input
                  const onStateChange = (state) => {
                    console.log('onStateChange', state)
                    onChange(state)
                  }

                  return (
                    <FormField
                      id={id}
                      label={label}
                      fieldCols={fieldCols}
                      labelCols={labelCols}
                      controlCols={controlCols}
                      inputClass={inputClass}
                    >
                      <Select
                        name={name}
                        onChange={onStateChange}
                        placeholder="Select state"
                        valueKey="id"
                        options={addressData.states}
                        labelKey="stateLabel"
                        optionRenderer={option => `${option.stateShortName} (${option.stateName})`}
                        value={input.value}
                        selectValue={Array.isArray(input.value) ? input.value : undefined}
                      />

                    </FormField>
                  )
                }}
                name="state"
                id="state"
                label="State."
                fieldCols={6}
                labelCols={3}
                controlCols={6}
              />

            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Field
                component={props => {
                  const { input, id, placeholder, type } = props
                  const { fieldCols, labelCols, controlCols, label, inputClass } = props
                  const { name, value, onChange, onBlur, onFocus } = input
                  const inputProps = {
                    name,
                    value,
                    onChange,
                    onBlur,
                    onFocus,
                  }
                  const onSuburbChange = (value) => {
                    console.log('onSuburbChange: ', value)
                    this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
                      input.onChange(value)
                      updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
                    })
                  }

                  return (
                    <FormField
                      id={id}
                      label={label}
                      fieldCols={fieldCols}
                      labelCols={labelCols}
                      controlCols={controlCols}
                      inputClass={inputClass}
                    >
                      <Select.Async
                        {...inputProps}
                        onChange={onSuburbChange}
                        valueKey="id"
                        labelKey="suburbName"
                        loadOptions={handleSuburbSearch}
                        backspaceRemoves={true}
                      />
                    </FormField>
                  )
                }}
                name="suburb"
                id="AddressLocation"
                label="Suburb."
                fieldCols={6}
                labelCols={3}
                controlCols={9}
              />

            </Row>
            <Row>
              <Field component={StaticText}
                name="postcode"
                id="postcode"
                label="Postcode."
                fieldCols={6}
                labelCols={3}
                controlCols={9}
              />

            </Row>
          </Panel>
        )

      }

      Address.propTypes = {
        handleSuburbSearch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      }

      const AddressForm = reduxForm({
        form: ADDRESS_FORM_NAME,
      })(Address)

      export default AddressForm
```

The problem is with the following function in the address component below and with setState which it says is undefined -

```
         const onSuburbChange = (value) => {
          console.log('onSuburbChange: ', value)
          this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, () => {
            input.onChange(value)
            updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, sectionPrefix)
          })
        }
```

You will note there is a console.log for "value". This produces the result:

`onSuburbChange:  Object {id: 6810, suburbName: "Eaglehawk", postcode: "3556", state: "VIC"}`

I am using React-Select as the async dropdown. This all works. If I select an option I get dropdown options but select one and it gives me the error.

I am using react state here for selectSuburb options as I dont need to update redux with this - just react state.

It seems all right but I still get the error. Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: You are setting state for a stateless functional component thats why it gives you this error

Comment: Could you elaborate. I am unsure as to how to rectify this.  I thought I set state in the container specifically in the constructor for onSuburbChange. How do I fix this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific error is caused by the fact that the `<Address />` component is a stateless functional component and cannot have a `this.state` object or a `setState` function in it. However, more generally it looks like you are expecting state and functions from the `<AddressContainer />` component to be available to the child `<Address />` component, but that cannot happen. In this case, you are wanting to modify the state of the parent by calling `setState` on the child.

A child React component (in this case `<Address />`) will only have state/functions/properties from its parent that are *explicitly passed down as props to that component.* If you want to change the local state of a component it *must happen on the component with the local state*. If you want to have a child component trigger some type of function call on the parent, then that function must be passed down as a prop to the child and the child can call it.

If I understand your code correctly, you want 3 things to happen when the Suburbs FormField is changed, in this order.

1. The `selectedSuburb` state on `<AddressContainer />` is updated.
2. The `onChange` of the Redux-Form `<Field />` in `<Address />` is triggered.
3. The `updatePostCode` action is fired off.

If that is correct, then you will need to move your `onSuburbChange` to the `<AddressContainer />` and pass it to `<Address />` as a prop. However, you cannot call the `onChange` of the Redux-Form `<Field />` inside `<AddressContainer />`. Therefore, you can make that function expect to receive a callback function that will be fired off after the state updates. Then you can define the callback in the child component but the state-changing function in the parent. As long as you pass down needed props on the parent, such as  `updatePostCode` and `sectionPrefix`, you'll be golden. Here's what it would look like:

**AddressContainer**

```
export class AddressContainer extends Component {
  /* Everything else in this component */

  onSuburbChange = (value, callback) => {
    this.setState({ selectedSuburb: value }, callback);
  }

  render() {
    /* Other stuff inside render */

    return (
      <Address 
        initialValues={initialValues}
        addressData={addressData}
        handleSuburbSearch={this.handleSuburbSearch}
        onSuburbChange={this.onSuburbChange}
        updatePostcodeValue={this.props.updatePostcodeValue}
        sectionPrefix={sectionPrefix}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

**Address**

```
export const Address = (addressProps) => {
  return (
    /* All other JSX */

    <Field
      component={props => {
        const { input } = props;

        const handleSuburbChange = (value) => {
          addressProps.onSuburbChange(value, () => {
            input.onChange(value);
            addressProps.updatePostcodeValue(value ? value.postcode : null, addressProps.sectionPrefix)
          });
        }

        return (
          <Select.Async
            onChange={handleSuburbChange}
          />
        )
      }}
  );
}
```

As you can see, there is going to be a naming conflict between the different `props` variables in the `<Address />` component, so I call the main props `addressProps` to avoid this.