# React, how access to class property into a callback

Tags: reactjs, class, properties, callback

I'm new in React development.. this is the code I've wrote

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { videos: [] };
    YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: 'Led zeppelin'}, function(videos) {
        this.setState({ videos });
    });
}
```

but when running i've this error into the console

```
proxyConsole.js:56 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined
    at index.js:17
    at index.js:19
    at <anonymous>
```

the "*this*" variable is **null**.. why? How can i access to this.setState ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: binding issue use arrow function `(videos) => {`, check this ques also: [Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Comment: Right.. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 YTSearch({ key: API_KEY, term: 'Led zeppelin'}, (videos) => {
        this.setState({ videos });
    });
```

Try this