# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined - not using ES6 yet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Learning React using a Udemy course. Ran into the error while trying to output state value:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

// Create a new component and make this component produce some HTML

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            term: ''
        };
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <input onChange={this.onInputChange}></input>
                Value of the input : {this.state.term}
            </div>
        );
    };

    onInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({term: event.target.value})
    }; }

export default SearchBar;
```

Could you please help explain the error?

Comment: This question has been asked and answer many times. Bind `this`, use arrow functions. Etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined

Answer (score 0):

add to your constructor

`this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);`

or use an arrow function in your HTML

`<input onChange={e => this.onInputChange(e)}></input>`

or use an arrow function in your class

`onInputChange = (event) => { ... }`