# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I know that there are plenty of answers on this, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined). I did add the `.bind(this)` in the component constructor. I also tried the fat arrow method (`fakeApiCall = ()=>{ ... }`) but when I click `Change Me`, this error still displays:

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count : 1000
    };
    this.fakeApiCall = this.fakeApiCall.bind(this);

  }

  fakeApiCall (){
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(function(response){
    // the response comes back here successfully
      const newCount = response.data.length;
    // fail at this step
      this.setState({ count : Math.floor(newCount) });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <span style={{ fontSize : 66 }}>{this.state.count}</span>
        <input type='button' onClick={this.fakeApiCall} value='Change me' />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `fakeApiCall` function is bound to your context, but the function callback in `axios` is not.

To solve this, you can use an arrow function, as they automatically bind with your class. You can also do it for `fakeApiCall` and remove it's binding :

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: 1000
        };
    }

    fakeApiCall = () => {
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(response => { //This is an arrow function
                const newCount = response.data.length;
                this.setState({ count: Math.floor(newCount) });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <span style={{ fontSize: 66 }}>{this.state.count}</span>
                <input type='button' onClick={this.fakeApiCall} value='Change me' />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```