# clear form on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to clear the form onClick with react. The event triggers, but when I try to setState to " " it tells me cannot set state of undefined.

I've tried setting the state to empty in several ways.

```
onHandleChange(e) {
this.setState({
input: e.target.value
});
}

clearForm(e) {
e.preventDefault();
const input = this.state.input;
console.log("input", input);
this.setState({
  input: ""
});
}
```

I've also tried to do it inline, with `onClick={(this.form.elements["text-input"].value = "")}`.

```
<button
  className="reset btn btn-danger"
  type="reset"
  id="resetInput"
  value="reset"
  onChange={this.onHandleChange}
  onClick={this.clearForm}
>
  Reset
</button>
```

My expected output is that the value of the input should be nothing. Empty string. However, that's not happening... i'm not resetting the state.

Comment: I don't see input textbox, all i see is button on which you have applied `onChange` which should not be there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you are not binding this correctly to `clearForm` function.

`Cannot set State of undefined`. This error means in `this.state`, **this** is undefined

Use `arrow` function to correctly bind `this` context.

Try this code

```
clearForm = (e) => {
```

Comment: Or bind this function in Class constructor ```this.clearForm = this.clearForm.bind(this)```

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnClear').click(function(){                
            if(confirm("Want to clear?")){
                /*Clear all input type="text" box*/
                $('#form1 input[type="text"]').val('');
            }                   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set state for all the values of the form input to be empty strings on click of that clear button.