# Issue of using setState function in ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a Reactjs application, and want to update state using

`this.setState({})`

But its saying cannot read property of "setState" is undefined.

Here is my Code.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    volume: 0
  }
  this.handleOnChange = this.handleOnChange.bind(this);

}

handleOnChange(value) {
  this.setState({
    volume: value
  })

}
```

> Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined.

Comment: Share full file code. Do you `import React from 'react'` ?

Comment: And also if you use class syntax you need to do `class YourComponent extends React.Component`

Comment: Yes imported React

Comment: Well I found its solution and it works for me

Comment: I am not able to use Arrow function.. do you guys know about that?

Comment: Share original code with error (in your question) and we can share an answer for other people.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)