# convert functional component to class component in React js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, react-state, react-ref

In my project I have used class components rather than functional components as I am getting all function components in every website. Can you help me to convert functional component to class component. And please help me to default the first value needed to select for giving multiple links.

This is the code sand box code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-dt504

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120,
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
}));

export default function SimpleSelect() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
  const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = event => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
     
      <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          labelWidth={labelWidth}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: can you please help me on default first value selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this does the job for you

Some articles : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks

[Converting React function component to class component issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43695583/converting-react-function-component-to-class-component-issue)

### EDIT

To select the first value, in your code pass the exact value like this
**const [age, setAge] = React.useState("10");**

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Menu from '@material-ui/core/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';

export default class SimpleMenu extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      anchorEl: null
    };
  }

  handleClick = event => {
    this.setState({anchorEl: event.currentTarget});
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({anchorEl: null});
  };

  render() {
    let { anchorEl } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          aria-controls="simple-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          Open Menu
        </Button>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me on default first value selected

Comment: check the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-djgqs . Added the edit there.

Answer (score 4):

`useState` hook: initial state is given to `this.state` in constructor and use `this.setState` to merge in key-value state update value pairs.

`useEffect` hook: with empty dependency array is roughly equivalent to `componentDidMount` lifecycle function, so move that logic there.

`useRef` hook: just use a standard react ref.

`useStyles` hook: keep the callback function consuming theme and use the `withStyles` HOC decorator.

```
import React, { Component, createRef } from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";

const useStyles = theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    minWidth: 120
  },
  selectEmpty: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
  }
});

class SimpleSelect extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: "",
      labelWidth: 0
    };

    this.inputLabel = createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ labelWidth: this.inputLabel.current.offsetWidth });
  }

  handleChange = event => this.setState({ age: event.target.value });

  render() {
    const { age, labelWidth } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
          <InputLabel
            ref={this.inputLabel}
            id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          >
            Age
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
            id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
            value={age}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            labelWidth={labelWidth}
          >
            <MenuItem value="">
              <em>None</em>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
        </FormControl>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(useStyles)(SimpleSelect);
```

[image: Edit Material demo]