# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

Tags: reactjs

**What I am trying?**

Trying to set the value of input type text in state

**What did I search so far?**

[React - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined?rq=1)

but this does not answer my issue

**Error Details**

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

This error is coming when setting the value of email in the function setEmailVal

[image]

**Component**

```
import React from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {email: ""};
    }

    setEmailVal(val) {
        this.setState({email: val.currentTarget.value});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text" onChange={this.setEmailVal} value={this.state.email} />
        );
    }    
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: You can try to change `this.setState({email: val.currentTarget.value});` to `this.setState({email: val.target.value});`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you declare your function in the following manner

```
    setEmailVal = val => {
        this.setState({email: val.currentTarget.value});
    }
```

It works fine.

If you wish to do it in the other (old, if I am not wrong) way, then you'd need to bind the function to the class for the subcomponent, i.e. the onChange handler in the class to "see" it:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {email: ""};
        this.setEmailVal = this.setEmailVal.bind(this);
    }
```

Lastly, you could do a direct bind inside the return component itself

```
        return (
            <input type="text" onChange={this.setEmailVal.bind(this)} value={this.state.email} />
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can fix this by changing `setEmailVal` to an arrow function.
Should look like this:

```js
setEmailVal = e => {
   this.setState({email: e.currentTarget.value});
}
```

Have a look at [this](https://oleg008.medium.com/arrow-functions-in-react-f782d11460b4) for more information on the subject.