# Using setState in 'async function with parameters' - used for onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am running a next.js app, with a file "temp.js" in the /pages directory.
My code (temp.js) is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from '@mui/material';

class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    state={
        someState: false
    }
    handleClick = async(someValue) => {
        this.setState({ someState: true });
        // await someAsyncFunction(someValue);
        console.log(someValue);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(12)}>
                Click me.!
            </Button>
        )
    }
}

export default SomeClass;
```

Stack Snippet (using `button` instead of MUI `Button`, but that doesn't matter):

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2017,react,stage-3">
class SomeClass extends React.Component{
    state={
        someState: false
    }
    handleClick = async(someValue) => {
        this.setState({ someState: true });
        // await someAsyncFunction(someValue);
        console.log(someValue);
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(12)}>
                Click me.!
            </button>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<SomeClass />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/regenerator-runtime@0.13.2/runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js"></script>
```

This gives the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')

   7 | }
   8 | handleClick = async(someValue) => {
>  9 |     this.setState({ someState: true });
     |         ^
  10 |     console.log(someValue);
  11 | }
  12 | render(){
```

This function would work fine if the 'someValue' was not required.
Need help. Please ask for any clarifications.

Comment: *"This gives the following error:"* ***What*** error? All you've shown is something pointing to a `.`. Other than not handling rejections (see below), that code looks like it should run.

Comment: Side note: If you're calling an `async` function from a non-`async` function, always be sure to handle promise rejections. Otherwise, they won't be handled by anything.

Comment: sorry, just updated with the error.

Comment: Thank you for updating the question with the error, but the code shown in the question will definitely not produce that error. `handleClick` is an arrow function in a context where it will close over `this` correctly, so `this` will not be undefined. The code you're running that has this error must be different from the above.  Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I also tried using onClick={async()=>{await this.handleClick(12)}}, but was getting same error.

Comment: If calling `handleClick` throws an error then adding logic that deals with the return value of `handleClick` isn't going to help.

Comment: (Blast, it'll be hard to create  a Stack Snippet for this, because of [this long-standing problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386096/update-the-version-of-babel-standalone-and-others-used-by-stack-snippets) with Stack Snippets. Damnit Stack Exchange! Fix the darned things!)

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) instead? That is because like what @T.J.Crowder pointed out, it is not possible to reproduce your bug in a stack snippet and we need to see what could've gone wrong: the way the code is written in your question now _should_ work.

Comment: @KonarkVerma - I've copied your code into a Stack Snippet (using `button` instead of MUI's `Button`, which is not going to affect what you've described). As you can see, it works just fine. Please edit the code in the `script type="text/babel"` tag in the snippet with your real code causing the error.

Comment: Currently I am using a next.js app and the code is exactly the same. I have created a file named temp.js in the /pages directory and pasted this code in the file. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please take a look?

Comment: @Terry can you please take a look?

Comment: There isn't much we could do since we are unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, that was not my intention. I can't appreciate enough the help by the work that you are doing. I just updated the situation, and pasted the entire code again. Sorry again.

Comment: Codesandbox has a Nextjs template you can start from. Or if your project is hosted in a github repo you can directly import it into a sandbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317154/react-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-setstate-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried deleting your node-modules, and doing an npm i again? It works for me sometimes.